# Extending generic Serializables with implicit conversions

Tags: scala, generics, implicit-conversion, serializable, scala-generics

I am trying to add extensions methods to `Serializable` types and there seems to be a hole in my understanding of the class. Here is a snippet of the basics of what I'm trying to do:

```
class YesSer extends Serializable

class NoSer 

implicit class SerOps[S <: Serializable](s: S) {
  def isSer(msg: String) = {
    println(msg)
    assert(s.isInstanceOf[Serializable])
  }
}

val n = new NoSer
val ln = List(new NoSer, new NoSer)
val y = new YesSer
val ly = List(new YesSer, new YesSer)
// n.isSer("non Serializable")
ln.isSer("list of non Serializable")
y.isSer("Serializable")
ly.isSer("list of Serializable")
```

`List` extends `Serializable`

It's obvious to me the line `n.isSer` won't compile, but it also seems that `ln.isSer` also shouldn't compile, as its "inner" type is NoSer. Is there some kind of coercion to `Serializeable` of the inner type of `ln`? Am I trying to do something absolutely bonkers??

Comment: The implicit conversion can be changed to only take collections of serializables, but then your `y.isSer("Serializable")` use case won't compile, and you can't have both implicit converters because that becomes an ambiguous implicit, which the compiler will reject.

Comment: I also expeerimented with this, and was able to have several implicit def conversions in scope at the same time
      `implicit def serToSerOPs[S <: Serializable](s: S) = new SerOps(s)`
      `implicit def serToSerOPsC[C[_] <: Serializable](c: C[_]) = new SerOps(c)`
      `implicit def serToSerOPsCS[C[_] <: Serializable, S <: Serializable](c: C[S]) = new SerOps(c)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` extends `Serializable`.  So `List[A].isSer(String)` is defined; the type of `A` does not matter.

`Serializable` is just a marker interface, used to indicate whether a class is designed to be serializable.  Whether or not you will be able to actually serialize the object depends on whether the entire transitive object graph rooted at the object is serializable.  Your `ln` will fail serialization at runtime with a `NotSerializableException` because it contains non-serializable types.  See [the javadoc for java.lang.Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) (which `scala.Serializable` extends) for more details.

Comment: This makes sense to me, perhaps my question is more along the lines of: what happens when you try to serialize `ln`. That's one I can surely answer myself though. Thank you!